# Can't open soft keybaord for autocompletetext

Tags: android, keyboard, autocompletetextview

I cannot get the softkeyboard to display on my samsung phone while testing an autocompletetext control in Eclipse.  I hit to physically touch the autocompletetext control to bring up the keyboard. Is there something different about AutoCompleteText controls that don't allow displaying a soft keyboard.  Below is my code in the onCreate method of my activity.  I will appreciate any help.

```
    autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.suggest);
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(autoComplete, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
        if (imm != null){
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
              } 
    //    imm.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);

        autoComplete.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String newText = s.toString();
                int len = newText.length();
           //     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text changed count = " + String.valueOf(len), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(len > 1)
                    new getData().execute(newText);
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

This will force the keyboard to show